# ServletContext cannot open properties file when executing JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm testing a REST controller using JUnit 4 and MockMvc. When I've written the test a few weeks ago, everything worked as expected. I've done some modifications in my code but I didn't change the JUnit test. Now, when I'm trying to run my tests, I have the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]
```

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyServerApplication.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MovieControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    // Some tests
}
```

And my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServerApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` file is located in `src/main/resources`. I didn't move this file, I didn't do anything but add some code in my services and add some properties in my file.

I read SO questions & doc, and tried these solutions:

- Check that `src/main/resources` is still in my test classpath
- Add `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` under the annotations in my test ; it didn't work so I tried to create a `src/test/resources` with a copy of `application.properties` inside, as suggested in one post
- Add `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` in the main class instead of the test class
- Add `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation
- Add `@WebMvcTest` annotation

I didn't try all of these solutions at the same time of course, I removed the added code after each failure.

I can still run my code without any issue though, only the test class results in `FileNotFoundException`.

How to solve this? And why do I have an issue with the test class but everything working fine when I run my server?

Comment: The fact that it is looking for a servlet context (and not a class path resource) makes me thing you are doing things you shouldn't be doing. Like having a `@PropertySource("application.properties")` somewhere in your code. Also you shouldn't use `@ContextConfiguration` with a spring boot based test, which is also the root of your issue.

Comment: Some suggestions  (may not exactly solve the issue)

1. You don't need `@ContextConfiguration` you can specify the classes in `@SpringBootTest` annotation.   
2. To Test only the controller layer you don't need `@SpringBootTest` this loads the whole application context. You can use `@WebMvcTest` and specif the controller you want to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyServerApplication.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MovieControllerTest { ... }
```

This is what you have on your test class. When using `@SpringBootTest` you shouldn't be using `@ContextConfiguration` (see [testing chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) of the Spring Boot Reference Guide).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MovieControllerTest { ... }
```

I would also suggest you use Spring Boot for testing instead of trying to do things manually. For mock mvc testing Spring Boot applications there are special slices and setup already done for you.

To enable this add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to your test and put `@Autowired` on the `MockMvc` field (and remove the setup in your `@Before` method).